# SwiftUI Widget: 'Expected a type' error on UILabel argument in an imported Objective-C header file

Tags: objective-c, swiftui, widget, bridging-header, ios14

I'm encountering a build error when **importing an Objective-C class** (via bridging header) into my **SwiftUI widget extension target**.

The Objective-C class defines a method method which accepts a UILabel argument. When building the widget, I receive an error on the method declaration on ‘**UILabel**’: ‘**Expected a type**’. I don't actually need to leverage this method in my SwiftUI project but it's part of the class that I do need to import.

I tried **adding the UIKit framework** to the Widget Extension target, and tried **importing the UIKit header** within the swift bridging file. No luck, I receive the same error.

I'm wondering if this is an incompatibility issue with using SwiftUI on the target and UIKit in the imported Objective-C file? Is there anything else I need to do to allow my SwiftUI extension to recognize UIKit classes?

Comment: UIKit view is not rendered in widget, but project with bridged obj-c compiled & run. Tested with Xcode 12b5 / iOS 14.

Comment: @Asperi - Do your bridged objective-c header files reference UIKit classes like UILabel? If so, did you have to do anything specific to get that working?

Comment: Nothing special, I tried subclass of UILabel and UILabel itself directly, UIKit was imported  in obj-c header, bridge header included only custom class header. All as usual. UIKit view was wrapped into SwiftUI representable.

Comment: Nothing special, I tried subclass of UILabel and UILabel itself directly, UIKit was imported  in obj-c header, bridge header included only custom class header. All as usual. UIKit view was wrapped into SwiftUI representable.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi - you helped me recheck my assumption that the widget target was failing. It was actually other extensions which did not support UI that failed.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem was not my widget extension** or sharing UIKit classes with SwiftUI. I realized that **my bridging header was shared across other extensions** (Siri, Watch) **which did not support UIKit** (or at least do not natively include UIKit frameworks). Adding UIKit dependent headers into the shared bridging header caused those **other extensions to fail building**.

To solve my problem, I created a **second bridging header** associated to the widget target *only* where I'm now able to include UIKit dependent Objective-C classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. So you need to set the "Objective-C BridgingHeader" from the SwiftUI Widget target, and the Objective-C files from the header gets imported to the SwiftUI class.